# Renomear um rotulo de grafico em Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

tenho um filtro de um dataframe:

```
F    3257703
M    2256044
```

com o código abaixo consegui exibir o grafico em pizza:

```
porcentagemSexo = sexo.value_counts(normalize=True)
rotulo = sexo.unique()
plt.pie(porcentagemSexo, labels = rotulo, autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.title('Porcentagem de Homens e Mulheres )
plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém gostaria de renomear os rotulos que estão como 'M' e 'F'
para 'Masculino' e 'Feminino'

Comment: [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/444445/edit) a pergunta e adicione o código do método `sexo.unique()`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o seguinte código:

```
porcentagemSexo = sexo.value_counts(normalize=True)
rotulo = ['Feminino', 'Masculino']
plt.pie(porcentagemSexo, labels = rotulo, autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.title('Porcentagem de Homens e Mulheres')
plt.show()
```

Na função `plt.pie()`, existe o parâmetro `label`, o qual recebe uma lista de strings e define como rótulo do seu gráfico.

Documentação do plt.pie(): [Clique Aqui](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html)

Comment: obrigado Vitor!

Answer (score 0):

O parâmetro `labels` do método `pie()` recebe um conjunto com os rótulos dos elementos do gráfico, que pode ser uma lista, tupla, objeto `ndarray` do numpy etc.
O seguinte exemplo apresenta de forma mais intuitiva como esses parâmetros influenciam o gráfico:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

nomes = np.array(['Grupo A', 'Grupo B', 'Grupo C'])
valores = np.array([10, 40, 70])

plt.pie(valores, labels = nomes, autopct='%.1f%%')
plt.title('Gráfico exemplo')
plt.show()
```

Com isso o seguite gráfico será obtido:
[image: figura_1]

Ou seja, basta trocar `rotulo` por um array com o nome das classes.